# Python program can't find Shellscript File

Tags: python, linux, shell

Hey i'm trying to run a shell Script with python using the Following lines:

```
import subprocess

shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["displaySoftware.sh"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

shellscript.stdin.write("yes\n")
shellscript.stdin.close()
returncode = shellscript.wait()
```

But when I run the Program it says that it can't find the .sh file.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: Try giving it the complete path of the `.sh` file. Maybe the "current path" where you're running the script is not the same as the path where the script is.

Comment: @Teer2008, if your `displaySoftware.sh` has executable permissions and starts with a valid shebang, you can just change `["displaySoftware.sh"]` to `["./displaySoftware.sh"]`, adding a leading `./`, and that's all you need to do -- no `shell=True`, no `sh`. And it works _better_ that way, because it honors your script's shebang to select the interpreter to use.

Comment: @Teer2008, ...mind, it would be better instead of hardcoding `./` to refer to the `__file__` attribute of your module to find the directory with your Python source code -- that way your script will still work if it's run from a different directory than the one with the source (which is a bug you still have with the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is missing "sh", you have to pass "shell=True" and "yes\n" has to be encoded.

Your sample code should look like this:

```
import subprocess

shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["sh displaySoftware.sh"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE )

shellscript.stdin.write('yes\n'.encode("utf-8"))
shellscript.stdin.close()
returncode = shellscript.wait()
```

This method might be better:

```
import subprocess

shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["displaySoftware.sh"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
returncode = shellscript.communicate(input='yes\n'.encode())[0]
print(returncode)
```

When running this on my machine the "displaySoftware.sh" script, that is in the same directory as the python script, is successfully executed.

Comment: This is _very_ inefficient. When you do this, you're telling Python to start **two** shells when it only needs one.

Comment: That is to say: `shell=True` prepends `['sh', '-c']` to the given command list, so you're running `sh -c 'sh displaySoftware.sh'`. You wouldn't ever do that on a command line, would you?

Comment: Moreover, `sh displaySoftware.sh` is itself bad practice, because it ignores `displaySoftware.sh`'s choice of shells to use and forces `sh` to be used to execute it, even if it's written for bash, or ksh, or zsh, or so forth.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does the second option fix the issues you pointed out Charles Duffy?